# Is there an equivalent to pytest's markers in jest?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs, pytest

I want to group all of the known flakey jest tests in a codebase with the equivalent of a marker in pytest ([docs here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/markers.html)) as a strategy to eventually remove them.

Does jest allow for this?  Is there some command line flag to do this?